# JavaScript Click Image Button

Tags: javascript, image, button, click, submit

This is my second question about clicking buttons in JavaScript but this one I'm really stuk on: I'm trying to click an image button with javascript however there's not much to go on as the source only gives this information about the image button

```
<div id="claimBtnDv" style="bottom:-30px; position:absolute; right:0; margin-top:0;">
    <input type="image" class="btnClaim" src="websitebuttonimage" onclick="alert('buttonclicked');">
</div>
```

I tried to do `document.getElementById('claimBtnDv').click()` but no success , are there other methods to use?

Comment: it works for me - http://jsfiddle.net/wMRbn/

Comment: You get the message 'button clicked' when you use document.getElementById('claimBtnDv').click() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't change the HTML and you need to click the image using javascript, you can go into the child nodes to find the image. This is pretty easy since a class name is provided.

```
var nodes = document.getElementById('claimBtnDv').childNodes;

for ( i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++ ) {
    if ( nodes[i].className === "btnClaim" ) {
        console.log("clicking!");
        nodes[i].click();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right. Updated code.

Although, it won't result in an error as the loop would exit after the last node anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Your code almost works - just change your `class="btnClaim"` to `id="btnClaim"` - and the `getElementById` will work - http://jsfiddle.net/wMRbn/1/

```
document.getElementById('btnClaim').onclick = function () {
    alert ( "click" );
}​
```

**UPDATE**
To get an element without an `id` you can do this - get the parent element by `id` and attach an event listener to its' `input` child - http://jsfiddle.net/wMRbn/3/

```
var img = document.getElementById("claimBtnDv").getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
img.onclick = function () {
    alert ( "click" );
}​
```

Comment: I would change it if I could however that's what the source of the webpage outputs , you can't click a image button by it's classname can you ?

Answer (score -1):

it looks like it works in that case.  Are you trying to assign it different click events or something?

jquery would allow you to do something like:

```
$("input.btnClaim").click(function(){
  //in here can go a lot more functions, etc.
});
```

javascript would do (after you give it an id of 'btnClaim'):

```
var X = document.getElementById("btnClaim");
x.onclick = "JAVASCRIPT GOES HERE";  
//from what the wc3 doc looks like, you need to have it in quotes, 
//   but i may be mistaken.
```

Maybe that helps ?

Comment: I tried quotes but it still didn't work , I'm just testing to see if I can click it via document.getElementById() is there no other way to do this?

Comment: **Incorrect.** For `onclick` you are supposed to provide a function, not a string.

Comment: Yea, i am aware.  I was just copying from wc3....  
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp
I guess i forgot to define what the "javascript goes here" means.